# How to get sum of appended field

Tags: laravel

```
/**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['likes'];
```

I've added this `$appends` to my model in laravel.
And I want to get sum of this appended field.
How can I do that?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is `likes` and where does it come from? I assume it's not a database column but rather a custom attribute accessor?

Comment: @james do you want to calculate the sum of likes of something? please post all the model code

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what the question is but progmatically I prefer to use the [BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) library when calculating.

Hope this helps.